# How do I find one element after using Findelements in Selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to create this global method that click on this link called `"Categories"`. The ID (t_166) is dynamic, `Xpath` `(//*[@id="t_166"])` and "copy selector" `(#t_166)` use the `id` number also so they won't work.

So, I'm left with the html:

[image]

I figured class would be a good candidate. So... to start:

```
var categorymenu = driver.instance.findelement(by.classname("fontMediumBigColorGrey navigatorLinkClicked z-label")
```

And then I want it to find the category one and click on it, something like:
`categorymenu.getattribute(category).click()`;

Two problems.

Problem 1: The link's class changes depending if you've visited it previously, or the "linkclicked" part in it. It becomes "fontMediumBigColorGrey z-label" if you haven't been on it. Question: it won't be able to find categories if the class is different. How would I handle this?

Problem 2: There are many other links (like users) that use the same classes, so shouldn't I be using findelements and then isolate it by an attribute (category is this case) But findelements doesn't seem to be able to use getattribute (because there are many of them) so how do I cover that part?

Thanks!

Comment: In case you have the chance to contact the developer, I would do so and ask if they can give the elements an appropriate "name" or "id" tag that you can always use. This is also the preferred way according to the developers of Selenium. If this is not a possibility for you, then try the answers below. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use search by `XPath` to find your element:

```
var categorymenu = driver.instance.findelement(by.xpath("//span[text()='Categories']")
```

In code above you search for `span` element with `"Categories"` as its text value

Also you can try to ignore dynamically changing part of `id` attribute in following way:

```
var categorymenu = driver.instance.findelement(by.xpath("//div[starts-with(@id, 't_')][substring-after(@id, '-')='cave']/span")
```

Above code should search for `span` that is child of `div` with `id="t_XXXX-cave"` where `XXXX` is ignored part

**Note** You should also be aware that you will not be able to complete `categorymenu.getattribute(category).click();` as `categorymenu.getattribute(category)` (actually `categorymenu.GetAttribute(category)`) returns just a string value

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to see if the `span` has the `fontMediumBigColorGrey` `class`:

```
var categorymenu = driver.instance.findelement(by.xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'fontMediumBigColorGrey')]")
```

In case you want to see if the text is equal to "Categories":

```
var categorymenu = driver.instance.findelement(by.xpath("//span[text()='Categories']")
```

A trick that I sometimes use, and could be useful for you too - if you're using Chrome, open the console and edit the HTML in such a way that you delete the "id" tag. Then, right click and choose 'Copy > Copy XPath'. This will copy the XPath but neglect the ID (because you can't use it since it's dynamic).

Comment: The text command does not work. I can't seem to figure out why. It throws an "element not visible" exception. I've an implicit timeout and I can see it. It is visible. 

And thanks for the XPath suggestion, may prove handy in the future. Although in this case it doesn't work because it goes back to the ID of the whole menu.

Comment: No, not yet.

And I can't sort by class only, other links use it also.

Comment: Can you share a public URL or print screen of this web element? Usually, "element not visible" exceptions are thrown for complex elements that use JavaScript etc.

Comment: Sure, here's the element:
http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=b874303

And the code leading up to it:
http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=e98a3aa

the C# code is just:
"var categorymenu = driver.Instance.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[text()='Categories']"));
categorymenu.Click();"

Comment: Thanks for the screenshots. I don't think this is a complex menu and I don't understand why the xpath with text doesn't work for you, I have compared it with my code and I see no differences.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133003/discussion-between-j0ck3-and-happy-bird).